# Ajax.stop function with json request issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to read from a database some data but without waiting for the page to load, so I created an ajax post that starts sending data when page is ready, now after ajax completes I need to read the values from another file. The problem is that after the ajax completes, json that is reading the data is running indefinite.

JQUERY

```
<?php $url = $_GET['url']; ?>
var jQuery_1_11_0 = $.noConflict(true);
jQuery_1_11_0(document).ready(function () {
    var domain = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'lib/ajax.php',
        data: {
            action: 'get_all_seo_details', // function that collects data
            domain: domain // the domain that is being send to the function in order to get data
        },
        success: function (data) {
        // doesn't need to echo anything only to insert the data, which it done properly
        }
    });
  // Below is the second part of the script that starts when ajax stops
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $.getJSON('lib/get-details.php', function(data) {
            var twitter_followers = data.twitter_followers;
            $('#twitter-followers').html(twitter_followers);
        });
 // data is being read correctly but it loops repeatedly in the console without finishing
    });
});
```

PHP - get-details.php, reading the data from database after getting inserted with ajax

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    sec_start();
}
global $db;
$domain = isset($_SESSION['domain']) ? $_SESSION['domain'] : '';
if ($domain == '') {
    $domain = $db->query("SELECT * FROM seo_data");
} else {
    $domain = $db->query("SELECT * FROM seo_data WHERE domain = '$domain'");
}
$domain_now = $domain->fetch_assoc();
$twitter_followers = (int) $domain_now['twitter_followers'];
echo json_encode(array('twitter_followers' => $twitter_followers));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but when the first AJAX request stops

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function (){....
```

starts a new one with

```
$.getJSON('lib/get-details.php', function(data) { ...
```

When this second one ends, maybe

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function (){....
```

is called again which starts again the 2nd request and so on

Comment: In the console, after the ajax post request finishes, the getjson starts and starts repeateadly, but only yhe getjson, not also the ajax post.

Comment: Read again my answer. When the ajax post stops, getJSON is fired by ajaxStop. When this first getJSON ends, ajaxStop is fired again as an Ajax request just ended. ajaxStop fires getJSON a second time and so on.

Comment: You should put your getJSON call in the success callback of your post request. It will be called once, when the post request ends

Comment: $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    console.log("ajaxStop is called");
    $.getJSON('lib/get-details.php', function(data) {
       var twitter_followers = data.twitter_followers;
       $('#twitter-followers').html(twitter_followers);
    });
});

Comment: Try to add this console.log as in my previous comment to know if ajaxStop is called repetedly

Comment: I removed the ajax stop function and added only the  $.getJSON inside the success and it's working correctly i think.

Comment: Ajax stop is called repeatedly.